# exclude 'pencil sharpener' from the results if the client searched for 'pencil'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I am using tire and we face a search result problem.
We are searching for 'pencil'.

- 'red pencil' OK
- 'electronic pencil sharpener' NOT OK should not be included in the result set.

This is the tire settings on the model:

```
settings :analysis => {
            :analyzer => {
              :my_analyzer => {
                "tokenizer"    => "lowercase",
                # "filter"       => ["synonym", "porterStem", "phonetic"]
                "filter"       => ["synonym", "porterStem"]
              }
            },
            :filter => {
              :synonym => {
                  "type" => "synonym",
                  "synonyms_path" => "#{Synonym.path}"
              }
            }
          } do
    mapping do
      indexes :commodity_code
      indexes :commodity_name
      indexes :long_description, analyzer: 'my_analyzer'
      indexes :short_description, boost: 10, analyzer: 'my_analyzer'
```

Answer (score 0):

The query `electronic pencil sharpener` will be translated to `electronic OR pencil OR sharpener` by default.

If you want to exclude documents containing `sharpener`, use a query like this: `electronic OR pencil NOT sharpener` or `+electronic +pencil -sharpener`.

Have look at `bool` and `match` queries to express conditions like these in the Query DSL; https://github.com/karmi/tire/tree/master/test/integration

Comment: we don't know if the user enters 'pencil sharpener' or 'red pencil'... So we don't know which word to exclude...